# How to use PHP for templates other then switch

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes, friendly-url

I have a PHP class to switch pages using this method:

```
$urlp = '/website/';
include 'phpclass.php';

$url = new thisurl($urlp);
if(!$url->segment(1))$page = 'home'; else $page = $url->segment(1);
    Switch ($page) 
    {
        case 'home': //include 'page/homepage.php'; 
            echo "Home";
            break;
        case 'about': 
            echo "About";   
            break;
        default: 
            echo "Page not found!";     
            break;
    }
```

It works with .htaccess file that i will not include for now, same as the php class. that's because i'm looking for an alternative way ton just switch pages or whatever, include files dynamically (I also have a bigger version with buffer).. so my question is what other good methods i can use to achieve same results in a better way.

Comment: Use a class autoloader, so you can replace the switch with a simple `new $page`.